# importing tensorflow(gpu) shows error: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.381.22: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory?

Tags: tensorflow

Have ubuntu 16.04, CUDA v8 and cudnn v5.1 installed.I followed the procedure of official site using anaconda. The error is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.381.22: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.381.22: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I have the libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.82 located in usr/lib/nvidia-375/ but not the one the error is for?

Comment: For all the googlers checkout the solutions listed in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678439/importerror-libnvidia-fatbinaryloader-so-375-39-cannot-open-shared-object-file