# ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nvidia, cudnn

```
    import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have installed tensorflow 1.4

cuda - cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb  && cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb

cuDDN - 6.0

can you suggest me how to correct this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678439/importerror-libnvidia-fatbinaryloader-so-375-39-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

Answer (score 6):

yes, it is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678439/importerror-libnvidia-fatbinaryloader-so-375-39-cannot-open-shared-object-file),
I too had the same problem.

I just added
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-384`
this line at the end of `.bashrc` file. And solved my problem.

This will work only if you have `libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90` inside `/usr/lib/nvidia-384` and if you don't then sorry, I don't know the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file doesn't exist on my system at all. I also can't find which package should contain it. (On Debian, it has its own package, but not on ubuntu / nvidia-cuda)

Comment: try to update your nvidia drive or re-install from offical nvidia website http://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in  but I am not sure this will work or not. @JonWatte

Comment: Re-installing the driver from the NVIDIA website solved it. Apparently, uninstalling some other NVIDIA packages also removes this library. Broken package management :-(

Comment: Re-installing the driver fixed the issue, but error showed up after a restart. Finally this answer helped me out.